# Linear Interpolation of 2 Vector3 by unit of distance rather than factor in THREE.js

Tags: vector, three.js, interpolation

Apologies for any wording and incorrect references, 3 dimensional maths is new to me!

Problem:

- I have two points in 3D space **A**: `(1,2,3)` and **B**: `(6,5,4)`
- I have a distance **L**: 10
- What is the 3D point **C** as defined as **A TOWARDS B** at a **UNIT** of **L**?

Notes:

- Distance of L is **not a factor** of the distance between A or B, there `.lerp()` is not the right tool here
- L can be both greater and smaller than the distance between A and B.

I'm using `THREE.js`, but any language examples are welcome!

Workings so far:

- Calculate distance between A & B -> **D**
- Get factor of D in relation to our target value L -> **R**
- Apply .lerp() with A towards B with factor R

```
function lerpUnit (x1,y1,z1,x2,y2,z3,distance) {
   ... ???
   return {x3,y3,z3}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could achieve this with just the methods provided by [`THREE.Vector3()`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/math/Vector3)

- First you could subtract vecB - vecA to get a parallel vector that originates at (0, 0, 0).
- Second, use `normalize()` to turn this vector into a "unit vector", which means no matter which way it's pointing, its length will always be 1.
- Third, multiply the vector by L, so `length = 1 * L`
- Lastly, move this new parallel vector back to its initial position with `+ vecA` to get the final position. It will land somewhere inside or beyond the line segment created by **A** and **B**

```js
var vecA = new THREE.Vector3(1, 2, 3);
var vecB = new THREE.Vector3(6, 5, 4);
var L = 10;

// Create new vector
var direction = new THREE.Vector3();

// Assign positionB
direction.copy(vecB);

// Subtract positionA to get a vector starting at (0, 0, 0)
direction.sub(vecA);

// Normalize to get a vector of lengh = 1
direction.normalize();

// Multiply by new length
direction.multiplyScalar(L);

// Add positionA to return vector to initial start point
direction.add(vecA);

// Output to log to see result
console.log(direction.toArray());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.117.1/build/three.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: sort of one-liner: `var C = new THREE.Vector3().copy(vecA).addScaledVector(new THREE.Vector3().subVectors(vecB, vecA).normalize(), L);` :)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, I just expanded on by workings far by using `.lerp()` but passing in a ratio's value, eg:

```
function lerpUnit (vectorA, vectorB, intendedDistance ) {
   const aToBDistance = vectorA.distanceTo(vectorB)
   const adjustedFactor = intendedDistance / aToBDistance
   return new THREE.Vector3().lerpVectors(vectorA, vectorB, adjustedFactor)
}
```

or 1 liner: `const vectorC = new THREE.Vector3().lerpVectors(vectorA, vectorB, intendedDistance / vectorA.distanceTo(vectorB))`